# Images don't resize to the grid after hover function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I want to create a map, which is made up of 64 images. Each image has two corresponding images, which show up after one another when the user hovers over them and then go back to the first image. That part is working. The problem I am running into is that the images don't stay in the right size after the user hovers over them. I want the images to stay in the grid.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlU63.jpg)

Here is the code (also apologies, I am still learning and I hope this is not to messy, perhaps I am overseeing something super obvious):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: Arial;
        background-color: yellow;
    }



    .column {
        margin-top: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        float: left;
        width: 12.5%;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .column img {
        border: 0.5px solid yellow;

        float: left;

        height: 100px;
        background-size: cover;
    }



    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<body>


    <head>

    </head>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="list">
                <img src="A/1.jpg" ; class="preview" ; style="width:100%">
                <img src="B/word1.jpg" ; class="preview" ; style="width:100%">
                <img src="C/1b.jpg" ; class="preview" ; style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <img src="A/9.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/17.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/25.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/33.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/41.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/49.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/57.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/10.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/18.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/26.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/34.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/42.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/50.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/58.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/11.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/19.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/27.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/35.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/43.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/51.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/59.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/4.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/12.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/20.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/28.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/36.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/44.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/52.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/60.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/5.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/13.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/21.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/29.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/37.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/45.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/53.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/61.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/6.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/14.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/22.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/30.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/38.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/46.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/54.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/62.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/7.png" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/15.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/23.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/31.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/39.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/47.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/55.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/63.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="A/8.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/16.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/24.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/32.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/40.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/48.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/56.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img src="A/64.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".preview").hide();
            var myInterval = false;
            $("div.list").each(function () {
                $(".preview:first", this).show();
                $(this).height($(".preview:first", this).height());
            });
            $('.preview').hover(function (e) {
                var $imgGrp = $(e.target);
                var $parent = $imgGrp.parent();
                var $firstImage = $parent.children('.preview:first');
                var iOffSet = $imgGrp.offset();
                myInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    var $nextImg;
                    $firstImage.hide();
                    if ($imgGrp.next('.preview').length == 0) {
                        $imgGrp.fadeOut('normal');
                        $imgGrp = $firstImage;
                        $nextImg = $imgGrp;
                    } else
                        $nextImg = $imgGrp.next('.preview');
                    if ($imgGrp != $nextImg)
                        $imgGrp.fadeOut('normal');
                    $nextImg.css({
                        'top': iOffSet.top,
                        'left': iOffSet.left,
                        'position': 'absolute'
                    });
                    $nextImg.fadeIn('normal');
                    $imgGrp = $nextImg;
                }, 750);
            },
                function () {
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                    myInterval = false;
                });
        });


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would be really thankful if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really get the exact mechanics that you wanted, but this is an 8x8 grid with two images per grid cell - and the images show up on hover.

```js
// starting the grid
const imageGrid = () => {
  let html = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    html += `<div class="cell"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat?lock=${i}"/><div class="show-on-hover"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat?lock=${i}"/><img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat?lock=${i + 64}" /></div></div>`
  }
  return html
}
const grid = document.getElementById('grid')
grid.innerHTML = imageGrid()
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.cell img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.cell>img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7
}

.cell .show-on-hover {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.cell:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}

.cell:hover .show-on-hover img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cell:hover .show-on-hover img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid" class="grid-container"></div>
```

## EDIT - based on comment

Here's a new snippet, based on the clarifications of the original question

```js
// creating an object with a getter function
// the getter function takes care of the cyclic URLs:
// anytime you call this objects src property, it will
// return the URL that's next in the cycle
const tileObj = (urls) => {
  // i is set so it's an internal variable - actually this
  // is the "state" of the tileObj
  let i = -1;
  return {
    get src() {
      return urls[++i % urls.length]
    }
  }
}

// creating the image objects
const createImgArr = () => {
  // setting up the size of the image array
  const noTiles = 64
  const ret = []
  for (let i = 0; i < noTiles; i++) {
    // creating the image objects by pushing three URLs
    // per image object (you can push any number of URLs!)
    ret.push(tileObj([`https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat?lock=${i}`, `https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat?lock=${i + noTiles}`, `https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat?lock=${i + 2 * noTiles}`]))
  }
  return ret
}
const imgArr = createImgArr();

// starting the grid
(function(imgArr) {
  // creating the image cells
  let html = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    html += `
      <div class="cell" data-cellid="${i}">
        <img src="${ imgArr[i].src }" />
      </div>
    `
  }
  // adding the image cells to the grid
  const grid = document.getElementById('grid')
  grid.innerHTML = html

  // adding mouseenter event listener to the grid cells
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell')
  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
      // changing the image src on mouseenter
      const idx = Number(e.target.getAttribute('data-cellid'))
      const img = e.target.querySelector('img')
      // the image object takes care of cycling the src values
      // on hover - this is where the getter of that object
      // shows up
      img.src = imgArr[idx].src
    })
  })

})(imgArr);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.cell img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.cell>img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid" class="grid-container"></div>
```

I created a bit more advanced solution to your problem:

- there is an object (`tileObj`) that keeps track of what URL it should return (using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) function)
- the `createImgArr` creates all the `tileObj`s by feeding three different image URLs to the function (that returns the object)
- the grid is created much the same way it was before
- a `mouseenter` event listener is added to each `cell` that changes the `src` of the image in that cell (and the `getter` function returns the appropriate URL from the array of URLs it was "fed" on its creation)

So, the point is that the "cycling" of URLs is hidden in the object holding the URLs and so the code doesn't have a complex "loop" - each `tileObj` knows its own state, returning the URL that it's supposed to.

P.S.: you may have to wait a bit on the first `src` changes, as the images must be downloaded

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and sorry for making my question unclear. I want an 8x8 grid, which has 3 images per cell. The images change when someone hovers over it, like first img01 is displayed then you go over it with your cursor and the image in the gird changes to img02, then when you go over it again img03 is displayed and then it goes back to img01 when your mouse over it again. I also looked into the mouseover function, but didn't get it to work in this loop.
I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: I managed to create this loop, but the issue I am running into is that the images then scale to 100% of the width and get distorted instead of staying in the size of the grid.

Comment: @Maya OK, I think I understand now - let me do a quick snippet for that

Comment: @Maya I added an other solution - when you hover over any tile an image is set from the set a "cell has received". The loop is simple, and each item keeps track of what loop state it's in.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much. That is beyond the advice I expected. Also thank you for adding all these notes. Without the randomiser 'loremflickr' it would be the same 3 images, right?  What I am wondering now is there a way to push 3 specific images in each of the 64 tiles? My example image shows a bit that the single tiles together create an areal view. Each tile is supposed to have two specific corresponding images, which then get displayed in this loop.

Comment: @Maya you can put any number of image URLs in the `tileObj` - the only thing is that they have to be valid image URLs, otherwise they won't display. They can be different URLs, the same URLs - anything. The `loremFlickr` URLs are just placeholders that I used in the snippet, nothing else. If you have a different set of URLs, then they are just as good.

Comment: @Maya the only thing is that it's only possible to set the image array of a `tileObj` when it's created. If you want to be able to modify the set it's cycling through (change a URL, add/remove a URL), then those cases have to be also handled. But for the problem you described I figured it's enough to set the array at initialisation.

Comment: Mister Gergely! I figured it out! I needed to add ```'width':'12.5%'``` to the script in the ```$nextImg.css``` part! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Maya I'm glad that you found a solution! :)